# Slack bolt: trigger_id expired when trying to trigger app.client.views.open modal

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I am using slack@bolt 2.0.1 with "express": "^4.17.1" in a slack app which I built 1 year ago.

In my local Slack bot, I am having this issue with instantiating a command:

```
export const createTicketCommand = (app: App): Middleware<SlackCommandMiddlewareArgs> => async ({
  ack,
  body,
  context,
}): Promise<void> => {
  // Acknowledge the command request
  await ack();

 app.client.views.open({
      token: context.botToken,
      trigger_id: body.trigger_id,
      view: {
        type: 'modal',
        title: {
          type: 'plain_text',
          text: 'Workplace check-in',
        },
        close: {
          type: 'plain_text',
          text: 'Cancel',
        },
        blocks: [
          {
            type: 'section',
            text: {
              type: 'plain_text',
              text: ':man-biking: Now loading...',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });

 
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
};
```

And I get this error; it looks to me there is something wrong with `trigger_id`.

```
{"level":1,"time":"2021-04-23T07:44:39.725Z","msg":{"code":"slack_webapi_platform_error","data":{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_arguments","response_metadata":{"messages":["[ERROR] trigger_id expired [json-pointer:/trigger_id]"],"scopes":["channels:history","chat:write","commands","files:read","groups:history","im:history","incoming-webhook","mpim:history","users:read"]}},"name":"Error","message":"An API error occurred: invalid_arguments","stack":"Error: An API error occurred: invalid_arguments\n at Object.platformErrorFromResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@slack/web-api/src/errors.ts:94:5)\n at WebClient.apiCall (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@slack/web-api/src/WebClient.ts:188:13)\n at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"}}
```

Note that I am getting this error when I use `app.client.views.open`.

I am making a guess that the app is taking more than 3 seconds to respond, hence why `trigger_id` is getting expired, but why is this happening?

This is happening on my local development bot, production bot looks all good.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that 3 seconds delay.

You can find proper solution in https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/1131

Comment: Might be worthwhile putting some of the code into the answer to help others in future, it will be easier to find than a Github link which may not be around in future. Just a tip.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31460357)